# Using AMPscript in a Script Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

We need to update a record in Salesforce using a Script Activity within an Automation. Ideally, I would like to use the AMPscript `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()` function to achieve this as there is no equivalent function in SSJS.

I am aware that Script Activities only work with SSJS. I have tried including my AMPscript in a Content Area and getting SSJS to call it. For example:

```js
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
    try {
        var stream = ContentAreaByName("my content area name");
        Write(TreatAsContent(stream));   
    } catch(e) {
        Write(Stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```

This works in an email, but does not appear to be supported in a Script Activity.

Does anyone know of a solution for this? The only solution I can think of is to create a Connected App in Sales Cloud and then use the Sales Cloud REST API to update the Salesforce record using an SSJS Post() function. I can do this, but would prefer not to, if I can avoid it.

Comment: Actually, the Sales Cloud REST API option won't work as this needs a PATCH method which is not supported in SSJS.

Comment: Instead of a Content Area and ContentAreaByName, could you create a Landing Page with the AMPScript and use the HTTP.Get() from SSJS?

Comment: @VictorCorey, yes you could to that too. It's a bit hacky and would count as a page impression for billing purposes. I think we have come up with another solution which I will post as an answer once validated.

Comment: Any solution on this?

Answer (score 13):

Server-Side JavaScript gives us more flexibility. We can use Ampscript in Script Activities. I have used it. I am not claiming that this is the best solution, but we can do the same using some tricky way like this:

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var sfUpdateString;
var subId = "abc123";   // Assuming subkey is available to process

sfUpdateString = '';
sfUpdateString = '%'+'%[SET @status = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Subscription__c","'+subId+'"';
sfUpdateString += ',"Opt_in_Email__c","0","Opt_out_Date_Email__c",Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))]%'+'%'; 

Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(sfUpdateString);
Write(Platform.Variable.GetValue("@status")); // For display Status (testing purpose)

</script>
```

There are two main important steps :

Step-1. Create a string variable that contains Ampscript block like this

```js
sfUpdateString = '';
sfUpdateString = '%'+'%[SET @status = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Subscription__c","'+subId+'"';
sfUpdateString += ',"Opt_in_Email__c","0","Opt_out_Date_Email__c",Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))]%'+'%';
```

Step-2. Call SSJS function TreatAsContent to renders all included dynamic content.

Here is reference for [TreatAsContent with SSJS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentTreatAsContent.htm)

```
Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(sfUpdateString);
Write(Platform.Variable.GetValue("@status")); // For display Status (testing purpose)
```