# Automating Updating Campaign Members - SFMC to SFDC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, campaign, sales-cloud

I have a data extension that has 3 columns in it: ContactID (text), Journey Number (Number), and Responded (Date). Each row in the DE corresponds to a customer who either did or did not respond (based on if Responded is NULL) to a Journey (Identified by Journey number).

In SFDC, we have corresponding campaigns for each Journey. What I'm wanting to do, is automate the update of customer statuses into those campaigns in SFDC via Journey Builder. However, I can't seem to find a way to say, "ContactID belongs to this campaign (Journey Number). Does anyone know of a way to tie a SFDC campaign to campaign member update based on a value in a data extension?

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254153/how-to-update-campaign-member-status-throughout-a-journey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I input a new field in SFDC that corresponded to the Journey Number in SFMC. I then had a journey update that number in SFDC to the corresponding campaign.

I synced the Campaign Object from SFDC via the Connecter. I then ran a query to join based on the journey number field I had created on the SFDC campaign. I then ran a journey to update the campaign members based on Campaign ID (in join query), the journey number, and the contactID.

Answer (score 0):

To update campaign member statuses you'll need to synch over the Campaign Member object to SFMC.

1.) Create a query with:

- a SELECT statement that outputs the Campaign Member ID and the Status that you want to change for that campaign member.
- FROM statement that features your DE (A) and JOIN it with the Campaign Member(B) Synched DE ON A.ContactID = B.ContactId
- WHERE statement - filter by date added, etc.

2.) Create an Automation with this query and set to run hourly
3.) Create a Journey - select the DE from your query on #1, Add Campaign Member activity, select the Status in DE.  You can also try Object Activity and select Campaign Member object