# CreateSalesforceObject AMPScript method is failing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, automationstudio

I am using Cloud Page to sync Marketing Cloud Data Extension records from SFMC to Salesforce CRM custom Object. I am using CreateSalesforceObject AMPScript method to create salesforce object. Following are the components involved in the Automation:

1. SSJS Activity: This Activity Calls Cloud Page.
2. Cloud Page: This Page contains AMPScript to query records from Data Extension and create Salesforce object record using CreateSalesforceObject function.
3. Salesforce CRM Custom Object : This is the custom object where we sync data from SFMC

Records are syncing perfectly fine except one following issue. Cloud page is unable to sync more than 700 records in single call. So if Data Extension has 1000 records which needs sync, then automation runs, it sync around 700 records and then is fails. The number 700 is not consistent here. It sometime sync 750, sometimes 800.

I have raised case with Salesforce Support to understand is there is any limitation for this method.and they said that CreateSalesforceObject method is not intended to be used as a data dump, but rather process small volumes. But I did not receive any specific information regarding any limitation for CreateSalesforceObject method.

Also, When we added trigger on above custom object, SSJS Activity could only sync 400 records and it started failing when we tried to sync more than 400 records from single cloud page call.

We were able to sync upto 10000 records by calling same cloud page multiple time from SSJS activity using for loop and syncing 400 records per cloud page hit.

Does anyone know any specific limitation of CreateSalesforceObject method which could have caused this issue?

Comment: This sounds like a very flawed approach. Landing pages have short timeouts, SSJS scripts have less short timeouts, CreateSalesforceObject is super slow and you'll get all sorts of locking issues with using CreateSalesforceObject. Consider an Automation to dump file and then dataloader to import to CRM or try injecting into Journey Builder and let the Object Activity to the hard work for you.

Comment: This may or may not have any value to you and your scenario, but [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146111/using-ampscript-in-a-script-activity) shows how you can call an Ampscript function in a Script Activity.

Comment: By no means do not use Journey Builder for bulk Sales Cloud updates, you will run into issues with scalability and performance.   Take a look at the Bulk API method described here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286883/account-activity-or-object-activity-in-journey-builder-has-limits-to-update-like or consider using tools like MuleSoft. It’s a shame that there’s no easier way to achieve this using Marketing Cloud Connect.